# Visual Basic (Zoning or Space Formatting)

Tags: vb.net

Im trying to read from a text file and display in listbox using zoning. but my code is not working no matter what i try. Can you please help me fix it.

```
    Dim objFile As New  
    System.IO.StreamReader("C:\Users\Keeora\Desktop\Westville\Year 2\Semester 2\Istn\ass.txt")
    Dim strAlbumName As String
    strAlbumName = objFile.ReadLine()
    Do Until strAlbumName Is Nothing
        ' Dim fmStr As String = ("{0,25}{1,15}{2,5}{3,18}{4,15}{5,13}{6,18}")
        ListBox1.Items.Add(String.Format(strAlbumName))
        strAlbumName = objFile.ReadLine()
    Loop
    objFile.Close()
    objFile.Dispose()
```

this is what i need it to look like

ITEM PRICE QUANTITY SUB TOTAL TAX DISCOUNT TOTALCOST

SHIRT                                                                                                  R400   2         R800      R5               3%               781

but each item directly under the corresponding title

Any help will be so appreciated

Comment: Use a grid, not a listbox.

Comment: our lecturer requested us to use a listbox. Is there anyway to do it in a listbox though?

Comment: You would have to use a monospaced font to start.

Comment: Do it both ways - in the listbox and also in a ListView or DataGridView to show the lecturer how it looks when you use the right tool for the job

Comment: thanks so much! will have to do it like that